# Span Position Absolute Stripping background color

Tags: html, css

Having some problems...

```
<span style='position: relative; font-size:0px;'>
    <a href="x.php?x=1898&y=2019">
        <img  style='background:url(images/4.png)' class='xyz' data-alt-src='images/X.png' data-x='y' data-coords='1898, 2019' src="images/4.png"  />
    </a>
    <span style='position:absolute; display:block; right:0px; bottom:0px; font-size:15px; background-color:green; color:white; line-height:0px;'>&nbsp; 8 &nbsp;</span>
</span>
```

What I have here is one of many, each of these code blocks overlays text (in this case an 8) over an image. Each of the code blocks buts up against one another and then there are line breaks to create multiple rows, etc.

The problem is the `position:absolute` and the `background-color:green`. Without `absolute positioning`, the `background is green`, but it doesn't overlay, with `absolute positioning`, there is no background color.

How do I solve the issue easily and quickly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to remove/change the following from your inline styling:

```
line-height:0px;
```

For example, try it using the following:

```
line-height:10px;
```

You will also want to manipulate the size of the green span as needed.

Comment: That works, but it moves the overlay upward. Having a line height of 0 keeps the overlay in the bottom-right corner of the image it's being overlayed on, but without setting a line height or setting it to 10 (for example), the overlay remains to the far right, but moves up by a number of pixels. Any suggestions?